# Override validation messages from package in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this input in a custom package:

```
<input name="price" type="text">
```

The request class has the following rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'price' => ['required']
    ];
}
```

When the rule fails for price input, the message displayed is:

> The price field is required

Instead I would like to display:

> The super cool price is required

Editing `resources/lang/en/validation.php` is not an option, because the lang must be setted from the package itself. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Edit: following the docs on [how overriding package language files](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization#overriding-package-language-files) is not working having the following structure:

```
// resources/lang/packages/en/my-package/validation.php

return [
    'attributes' => [
        'price' => 'super cool price'
    ],
    'custom' => [
        'price' => [
            'required' => 'super cool price is required'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative is override the `messages()` function in the request class:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'price.required' => 'super cool price is required'
    ];
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'price' => ['required']
    ];
}
```